# The big bang singularity and entanglement

Tags: quantum-entanglement, big-bang, singularities

Since our universe began as a singularity would that mean that everything in the universe is entangled with itself?

I am not sure that makes sense, but hopefully some one can figure out what I am trying to ask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Particles entangled after the big bang](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55026/)

Comment: How do you know that the universe began as a singularity? There is no evidence for that.

Comment: Hi Paul, the link AccidentalFourierTransform suggests is indeed an exact duplicate of your question.

Comment: @CuriousOne: you are being unnecessarily pedantic. It is perfectly reasonable to ask *If the universe began as a singularity then etc etc* and, as Luboš showed, that question has a perfectly good answer.

Comment: @JohnRennie: I am merely presenting the OP with the actual state of physical knowledge. We have absolutely no evidence for a singularity. Moreover, I don't believe that anybody is even proposing a universal singularity search program in astrophysics. Eve the theorists are desperately trying to get rid of singularities in theories... so, if anything, we are trying to do exactly the opposite of what the OP is presuming. Am I wrong about any of that?